# Tabla con contenteditable, en un modal de bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo una tabla común y corriente dentro de un `html`, que relleno con un `ajax` de la siguiente manera (Obvio dentro de un `for` que me recorra todo el objeto obtenido en la consulta):

```
`<tr>
    <td># ${task.numero}</td>
    <td>${task.fecha}</td>
    <td>${task.cantini_productos}</td>
    <td contenteditable>${task.unidades_inicial}</td>
    <td>$ ${task.valorini_productos}</td>
</tr>`
```

Hasta ahí perfecto, pero cuando hago esto mismo dentro de una tabla que está contenida en un modal, no me toma el **contenteditable**, es decir, que no puedo editar campos que necesito editar...

Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias!

Comment: Al estar dentro de un modal, intenta ver si tiene algun elementos invisible superpuesto que no deje darle click, tambien puedes asegurarte intentando seleccionar el texto de las demas filas.

Comment: Por favor, adjunta un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)